# Implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'

Tags: java, android, admob

I want to add ads to my project but when i add the line below, it doesn't work:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'
```

these are the dependencies from the `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: yes i am sure  i have add it correctly

Comment: So what's the error?

Comment: @AbdoSrour could you please be a little more specific about the error you are getting? alike the question is currently written, this is nothing one could answer; adding any error message or stack-trace would improve your chances to get a reliable answer.

Comment: @ianhanniballake the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) should probably have the Play Services plugin in it's Prerequisites, in order to avoid confusion. I'm not absolutely certain that it is required, but I think it is likely required.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - it isn't required if [add the id to your manifest](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml) - that's all the Google Services Gradle Plugin does for you.

Comment: @ianhanniballake that makes sense... the correct answer should have been, to do just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely, that you might not have added the [Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) to the project, as well as the `google-services.json` file (which can be downloaded from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/)) - and so your application fails to authenticate.

Adding the `com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID` into the `AndroidManifest.xml` has the same effect, because the Play Services plugin  adds the values from `google-services.json` at build-time.

... when only using AdMob, the second option should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have inside top-level `build.gradle` file  reference to the `google()` repo or to `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`? Do you have some specific error inside log?

Comment: i don't have error when i put the implementation project doesn't work?

Comment: can you paste build.gradle file here? Did you synced gradle with project? Can you see any of classes from autocorrect when you start typing MobileAds inside kotlin/java files?

Comment: i synced then i run project on mobile phone it give me error

Comment: Do you see maybe this error? java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Comment: If yes, did you tried to initialize SDK from this tutorial: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new project and copy old project files and paste in a new one. If it should help!

Comment: yes i am sure app run well before add implementation